# why are my axis + legend breaks and labels displaying differently for each dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, axis, label

My data is contained in an excel workbook and for each sheet (~30+) I'm trying to create a graph like the one below.

I'm using Rstudio and I import one sheet and then run the code and save the graph, then load the next sheet and repeat.

My y-axis breaks aren't displaying the same on each individual graph, in some the "show" label doesn't appear and in others it does.

As for the legend breaks, the durations differ for each individual graph and I'd like to set a uniform legend but can't seem to set the breaks

```
    #cbbPalette <- c("#000000", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")

ggplot(data = Consolidated_Cadiz_prestartGB_p01, aes(x=Fix8, y=AOI, color = Duration)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.5) +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = rainbow(10) ) +
  #scale_colour_manual(values=cbbPalette) + ----- not working
  geom_line(color = "grey") +
  xlab("Fixation number") +
  ylab("Area of interest") +
  labs(colour = "Duration (ms)") +
  # "show" label isnt appearing on all graphs
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1:23, 25),
                     labels = c("show", "Bow", "Mast", "Boom", "Control lines", "Watch", "Wind indicator", "Sail", "Window", "Tell-tales", "Laser other", "Opponent", "Stern-opponent", "Sea", "Sea2", "Stern-sea", "Stern-sea2", "Non-laser boat", "Sky", "Other", "Coaches boat", "Pin buoy", "Committee boat buoy", "No cursor")) +
  #scale_shape_discrete(breaks=c(99, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000),
                       #labels=c("100", "500", "1000", "1500", "2000+")) + --not working
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")
  )
```

[image: linegraph - action against time]

EDIT:

```
> dput(head(Consolidated_Cadiz_prestartGB_p01))
structure(list(Fix8 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), AOIcode = c("sea2", 
"pinBuoy", "sea", "pinBuoy", "noCursor", "controlLines"), Duration = c(100, 
198, 563, 1059, 166, 298), AOI = c(15, 22, 14, 22, 25, 5)), .Names = c("Fix8", 
"AOIcode", "Duration", "AOI"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

EDIT 2: Y-axis issue is resolved, now need to set legend

Comment: Please paste into your question the output of `dput(head(Consolidated_Cadiz_prestartGB_p01))`. FYI, you can do `breaks=c(1:23,25)` instead of typing each number explicitly.

Comment: thannks for your comment, I've edited it accordingly. How does this info help? Thanks for the explicit typing comment, I did have it that way to begin with but whilst I was resolving old issues I ended up typing it out to see if it resolved the problem..code has been edited to reflect

Comment: To answer the question in your comment: It's hard to tell what's going wrong with your plot without seeing your data and how the data are encoded.  The data sample you posted doesn't actually include any rows with AOIcode equal to "show", so it looks like I'll need another data sample in addition to that one. Can you provide another data sample that includes a row with AOIcode = "show"?

Comment: No rows will have a value of show. What I was hoping to achieve was a gap similar to the one that I have at the top. The 'show' appears when there is a row in the sheet that contains 'bow'

Comment: I think adding `limits=c(1,25)` to `scale_y_continuous` will take care of showing "show" in all graphs.

Comment: thanks! that solved part 1 of my problem

Comment: For the duration, I think it would be `scale_colour_gradientn(colours = rainbow(10), 
                         breaks=seq(0,1000,200),
                         limits=c(0,1000))`. Set the limits and breaks to whatever values you wish (you'll presumably want to set `limits` to be at least the range across all of your data frames). You can use `colours = cbbPalette` if you want to use your custom colors.

Comment: If you read the data into a list first, you can get the appropriate `limits` range programmatically from the data. Using `library(readxl)` reading the data into a list would be something like `sheets = excel_sheets("myfile.xlsx"); dat.list = lapply(sheets, function(s) { read_excel("myfile.xlsx", sheet=s)})`. Then you can get the full range of the data from `dat.list` and also use `lapply` to produce all of your plots by operating on `dat.list`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can read the data into a single data frame with a column listing the source worksheet and then create a single faceted plot with a panel for every worksheet from the excel file.

Comment: There is a lot of new stuff for me in your last few comments so I'm going to work through your suggestions. I like the single dataframe idea, not sure if facet would be the best option for me though because i have to display the graphs individually later on..but an approach like this seems like it could work for me and help me avoid loading each sheet and creating graph individually